# Runtime ERROR : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.caucho.server.resin.EnvInit

Tags: java, cdi

When I checkout and run the [jee6-cdi](https://code.google.com/p/jee6-cdi/) I'm getting the below Run Time error. 
Any idea how to resolve this issue?

```
com.caucho.config.ConfigRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.caucho.server.resin.EnvInit
at com.caucho.config.ConfigException.create(ConfigException.java:168)
```

Comment: Which applicationserver or container are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't added the external library in build path

Comment: I have added all the dependencies in the pom.xml